# At core/graph/iterators.c:762 : Cannot create iterator

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

I am using the CytoTree package in R, which uses the igraph function to calculate pseudotime trajectory.

I have performed tSNE, UMAP, clustering analyses.

I have manually defined the root cells as follows, based on the clustering data:

```
cyt<-defRootCells(cyt, root.cells=c(13,16,21))
```

This function works, as now in the meta data of the cyt object, I can find a column "is.root.cells", where the clusters 13, 16, 21 are identified with a 1, and the other clusters with a 0.

When I run:

```
cyt<-runPseudotime(cyt, verbose=TRUE, dim.type="umap", dim.use=seq_len(2))
```

I get this error message:

**Error in distances(g, v = root.cells) :
At core/graph/iterators.c:762 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id**

I used the exact same steps for a previous analysis, on another laptop, and it all worked well.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This message means that an invalid vertex ID was passed to the `v` parameter of `distances`. It's not possible to say more without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, this seems unrelated to the usage of igraph, and related to CytoTree instead.

Comment: @Berengere If this is the function, it may help to review its source code: https://github.com/JhuangLab/CytoTree/blob/1c60ff8d9dd9cd5cfed4a44ec6c3e17727e306e2/R/pseudotime.R